# MS Teams, Adaptive Card, Copy-Paste functionality

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

MS Teams application ...

I send Adaptive Card to the client and Bot handles card actions.
How can I add/implement copy-paste functionality?

1. Client will copy the card to the clipboard and send it to a different client.

P.S.: I implemented "Link unfurling" functionality and can see "Copy" menu button but there is no one in the original Adaptive Card that I sent using ConnectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(messageActivity)

2. I think the Adaptive Cards actions won't work from a different chat (not Bot, Client to Client). Right? Maybe just links ... Or It can be handled?

Answer (score 0):

Copy-Paste is not supported for Adaptive Cards. However it is supported for Messaging Extension/Link Unfurling.

ME:

[image]

Copy Command:
[image]

Paste Screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I implemented it ... The big question is "copy-paste" functionality ... I have to implement it or something like that. Maybe ... Copy (to clipboard) a link from adaptive card or through the command or task or search. I'm trying to find out.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can create a custom compose extension command to read the card JSON received in a TurnContext object in Bot and then you can store it in a temporary memory and read it whenever required.

Comment: Do you mean "Messaging Extension/Link Unfurling"? I checked all of them. I can create a copy of the card using additional button of "More actions>...." menu.

Comment: But ... Client requirements ... 
1) Add "Copy" button into Adaptive Card;
2) Make a copy of the card and send it to selected user;
Is it possible?
Maybe ... Are the any workaround? ... 
Press "Copy" button of Adaptive Card to Copy the link and use it via "Link Unfurling" or ... Give User possibility to select User and resend the card. But ... I think there is no possibility to send the card to outside the bot (to User-User chat).

Comment: @imfantom - I am not sure but you can try these steps: 1) Click on copy button (Submit action) 2) Handle the request on server side and check if you are getting card payload 3) if card payload is available in turnContext, you can create another card using the existing card payload 4) Send the new card to another user using create conversation/update conversation.